# Is every simply connected domain regular?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, potential-theory

Recall that a domain $D \subseteq \mathbb C$ is called *regular* if for each point $x \in \partial D$, we have $\mathbf P_x\lbrack \tau_D = 0\rbrack = 1$, where $\tau_D = \inf\{t > 0 : B_t \notin D\}$, and $(B_t)_{t \ge 0}$ is a Brownian motion.

1. Is the domain $\mathbb D \setminus [0, 1)$ regular?
2. Is every simply connected domain regular?

Comment: By "domain" D, do you mean an open subset of ℂ ?  Must D be bounded? And what does the notation **P**_x mean?

Comment: @DanielAsimov by domain, I mean connected open subset of $\mathbb C$, which does not need to be bounded. $\mathbf P_x$ means $\mathbf P\lbrack - \vert B_0 = x\rbrack$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes to both. Both were already answered here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4389689/is-every-simply-connected-set-in-the-plane-regular-for-brownian-motion

So for Q1 we can use the simple-arc criterion.

> The regularity of every boundary point of an open set in $\mathbb R^2$ is in fact strongly related to connectedness. However, that's more a property of the complement of the set: Problem 4.2.16 in [1](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X18303433) which is:

> *Let $D\subset\mathbb R^2$ be open, and suppose that $a\in\partial D$ has the property that there exists a point $b\not=a$ in $\mathbb R^2\setminus D\,,$ and a simple arc in $\mathbb R^2\setminus D$ connecting $a$ to $b\,.$ Show that $a$ is regular.*

> The solution is provided in [1](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X18303433) section 4.5. The unit disc minus the line segment $[0,1)\times\{0\}$ clearly satisfies the properties of $D$ in that problem.

> [1](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X18303433) I. Karatzas, S. Shreve, *Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus.*

More generally for Q2, see Bass "probabilistic techniques in analysis" Prop. II.1.14
(or the article mentioned in the comments
["A remark on the probabilistic solution of the Dirichlet problem
for simply connected domains in the plane"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X18303433))

where they show that: *The Dirichlet problem is solvable for any simply connected domain in $\mathbb{C}$.*